# How to mock remote REST API in unit test with Spring?

Tags: java, unit-testing, rest, spring-test

Assume I have made a simple client in my application that uses a remote web service that is exposing a RESTful API at some URI `/foo/bar/{baz}`. Now I wish to unit test my client that makes calls to this web service.

Ideally, in my tests, I’d like to mock the responses I get from the web service, given a specific request like `/foo/bar/123` or `/foo/bar/42`. My client assumes the API is actually running somewhere, so I need a local "web service" to start running on `http://localhost:9090/foo/bar` for my tests.

I want my unit tests to be self-contained, similar to testing Spring controllers with the Spring MVC Test framework.

Some pseudo-code for a simple client, fetching numbers from the remote API:

```
// Initialization logic involving setting up mocking of remote API at 
// http://localhost:9090/foo/bar

@Autowired
NumberClient numberClient // calls the API at http://localhost:9090/foo/bar

@Test
public void getNumber42() {
    onRequest(mockAPI.get("/foo/bar/42")).thenRespond("{ \"number\" : 42 }");
    assertEquals(42, numberClient.getNumber(42));
}

// ..
```

What are my alternatives using Spring?

Comment: Do you leverage the DTO pattern?

Comment: @Manu Do you mean if I marshall to and from JSON into domain objects in my client?

Comment: More precisely, if you marshal/unmarshal into intermediate objects representing your domain entities in the network

Comment: @Manu No, I don’t have intermediate objects, only domain objects and JSON text.

Comment: Then I'd recommend start using the DTO pattern and proceed the same way you did for testing MVC controllers.

Comment: If you're already okay with Spring, the obvious choice is to use (and mock) RestTemplate.

Comment: @Manu Okay, could you explain that a little bit more? Give an example in an answer?

Comment: If you are using rest and leveraging the [DTO pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object), then I'd recommend you follow [this tutorial](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/unit-testing-of-spring-mvc-controllers-rest-api/).

Answer (score 19):

If you use Spring `RestTemplate` you can use `MockRestServiceServer`. An example can be found here [REST Client Testing With `MockRestServiceServer`](https://objectpartners.com/2013/01/09/rest-client-testing-with-mockrestserviceserver/).

Comment: If you don't use Spring RestTemplate, you can check WireMock. However this will start a server in the background.

Comment: [This](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/using-mockrestserviceserver-test-rest-client/) one is newer.

Comment: To be sure: I guess this only work if the tested client use the same instance of `RestTemplate`? In my case, the tested code instantiate its own `RestTemplate` internally and I don't have access to it. So I can't use `MockRestServiceServer`?

Answer (score 18):

Best method is to use [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/).
Add the following dependencies:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
        <artifactId>smack-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Define and use the wiremock as shown below

```
@Rule
public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(8089);

String response ="Hello world";
StubMapping responseValid = stubFor(get(urlEqualTo(url)).withHeader("Content-Type", equalTo("application/json"))
            .willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(200)
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").withBody(response)));
```

Comment: Where is aResponse() coming from?

Comment: @powder366 WireMock.aResponse()

Comment: Too bad WireMock requires Jitpack, and our IT Risk office forbids us to build it in production servers since it would introduce a vulnerability. For this reason, even if I like WireMock and I used it with success, I'm still looking for alternatives

Answer (score 12):

If you want to *unit* test your client, then you'd mock out the services that are making the REST API calls, i.e. with [mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) - I assume you do have a service that is making those API calls for you, right?

If on the other hand you want to "mock out" the rest APIs in that there is some sort of server giving you responses, which would be more in line of integration testing, you could try one of the many framework out there like [restito](https://github.com/mkotsur/restito), [rest-driver](https://github.com/rest-driver/rest-driver) or [betamax](http://betamax.software/).

Answer (score 11):

You can easily use **Mockito** to mock a REST API in **Spring Boot**.

Put a stubbed controller in your test tree:

```java
@RestController
public class OtherApiHooks {

    @PostMapping("/v1/something/{myUUID}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> handlePost(@PathVariable("myUUID") UUID myUUID ) {
        assert (false); // this function is meant to be mocked, not called
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }
}
```

Your client will need to call the API on *localhost* when running tests.  This could be configured in `src/test/resources/application.properties`.  If the test is using `RANDOM_PORT`, your client under test will need to find that value.  This is a bit tricky, but the issue is addressed here: [Spring Boot - How to get the running port](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30312058/86967)

Configure your test class to use a `WebEnvironment` (a running server) and now your test can use Mockito in the standard way, returning `ResponseEntity` objects as needed:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class TestsWithMockedRestDependencies {

  @MockBean private OtherApiHooks otherApiHooks;

  @Test public void test1() {
    Mockito.doReturn(new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED))
      .when(otherApiHooks).handlePost(any());
    clientFunctionUnderTest(UUID.randomUUID()); // calls REST API internally
    Mockito.verify(otherApiHooks).handlePost(eq(id));
  }

}
```

You can also use this for end-to-end testing of your entire microservice in an environment with the mock created above.  One way to do this is to inject `TestRestTemplate` into your test class, and use that to call *your* REST API in place of `clientFunctionUnderTest` from the example.

```
@Autowired private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
@LocalServerPort private int localPort; // you're gonna need this too
```

---

### How this works

Because `OtherApiHooks` is a `@RestController` in the test tree, Spring Boot will automatically establish the specified REST service when running the `SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment`.

Mockito is used here to mock the controller class -- not the service as a whole.  Therefore, there will be some server-side processing managed by Spring Boot before the mock is hit.  This may include such things as deserializing (and validating) the path UUID shown in the example.

From what I can tell, this approach is robust for parallel test runs with IntelliJ and Maven.

Comment: WARNING: Note that `assert` may be out-of-favor with some reviewers.

Comment: Solutions like WireMock allow you to copy/paste a serialized response and test how it gets deserialized by the code. On the other hand, when mocking the `RestTemplate` you are passing an already existent `ResponseEntity`, which makes the test way less powerful. As an example, WireMock would let you test different `Content-Type` response headers and let you see how they are handled

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the support for [Client-side REST Tests](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#spring-mvc-test-client) in the Spring MVC Test Framework.

Assuming your `NumberClient` uses Spring's `RestTemplate`, this aforementioned support is the way to go!

Hope this helps,

Sam

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example on how to mock a Controller class with [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/):

The Controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public Page<UserCollectionItemDto> getUsers(Pageable pageable) {
        Page<UserProfile> page = userService.getAllUsers(pageable);
        List<UserCollectionItemDto> items = mapper.asUserCollectionItems(page.getContent());
        return new PageImpl<UserCollectionItemDto>(items, pageable, page.getTotalElements());
    }
}
```

Configure the beans:

```
@Configuration
public class UserConfig {

    @Bean
    public UsersController usersController() {
        return new UsersController();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserService userService() {
        return Mockito.mock(UserService.class);
    }
}
```

The `UserCollectionItemDto` is a simple [POJO](https://spring.io/understanding/POJO) and it represents what the API consumer sends to the server. The UserProfile is the main object used in the service layer (by the `UserService` class). This behaviour also implements the [DTO pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object).

Finally, mockup the expected behaviour:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@Import(UserConfig.class)
public class UsersControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private UsersController usersController;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void getAllUsers() {
        initGetAllUsersRules();
        PageRequest pageable = new PageRequest(0, 10);
        Page<UserDto> page = usersController.getUsers(pageable);
        assertTrue(page.getNumberOfElements() == 1);
    }

    private void initGetAllUsersRules() {
        Page<UserProfile> page = initPage();
        when(userService.getAllUsers(any(Pageable.class))).thenReturn(page);
    }

    private Page<UserProfile> initPage() {
        PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(0, 10);
        PageImpl<UserProfile> page = new PageImpl<>(getUsersList(), pageRequest, 1);
        return page;
    }

    private List<UserProfile> getUsersList() {
        UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
        List<UserProfile> userProfiles = new ArrayList<>();
        userProfiles.add(userProfile);
        return userProfiles;
    }
}
```

The idea is to use the pure Controller bean and mockup its members. In this example, we mocked the `UserService.getUsers()` object to contain a user and then validated whether the Controller would return the right number of users.

With the same logic you can test the Service and other levels of your application. This example uses the [Controller-Service-Repository Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) as well :)