# Unit test involving Elasticsearch in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, elasticsearch

I'm using Spring Boot with `elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client` and I am currently writing unit tests.

My program is just a simplified REST API to call ES, thus my unit tests need either a mock of the ES database or a running ES instance and so far I haven't been able to do any these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, if you really write **unit** tests, they can't use any database or instance (or they are been integration tests).

I recommend to google how testing Spring Rest Client for [example](https://objectpartners.com/2013/01/09/rest-client-testing-with-mockrestserviceserver/), [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/), or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564533/how-to-mock-remote-rest-api-in-unit-test-with-spring). You just define what results you want from Elasticsearch.

If you really need integration tests, you can create any ES demo instance.

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks. I understand this isn't unit testing but so far it's the only relevant testing I thought of regarding my application.

Comment: So I am using WireMock now and I am rather satisfied, thanks a lot. Only disturbing thing I found, but it could be related to elasticsearch high level rest client or just me misusing things : I have to stubFor a post method to mock my update call and stubFor a put method to mock my create call.