# how to induce an error condition in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, web-services

I have spring boot application which calls a remote api service. The remote service can throw various exception conditions that include 1. Service not available 2. Parsing error . So we want to replicate those scenarios in our local environment to make sure our code handles those error response structure . If the remote service were able to provide such test cases this would have been easier but they said it is dynamically generated . I have been trying to research on how to create or induce those conditions but could not find anything as such . Even the slightest points would be of great help at this moment . Thank you.

Comment: You can create these scenarios by writing test cases

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock remote REST API in unit test with Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564533/how-to-mock-remote-rest-api-in-unit-test-with-spring)

Answer (score 0):

Check [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html) and [complete guide with examples](https://www.baeldung.com/restclienttest-in-spring-boot) for `MockRestServiceServer`.

I hope it'll solve your problem.