# Mock API responses in JUnit5 based tests using mockito: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, junit5

### Context

I am completely new to Java / JUinit  and I have some trouble understanding how to **mock the following API response**. In this `Extractor` class, I have a method `getManagers` (later to be used as a factory method to return `List<Manager>`)

```java
public class Extractor {
    ....
    public String getManagers(HashMap parametters, String base_url, String token) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2).build();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest
                .newBuilder(URI.create(String.format("%s/api/rest/query/HUB_REFERENTIALS/Employee/GD%s", base_url, assembleSemQL(parametters))))
                .header("API-Key", token).GET().build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        return response.body();
}
```

To get more familiar with **Mockito**, I started with a **trivial test**. The point is to be able to write tests execution of which should not depend on the REST API being actually called. `testGetManagers` check that `getManagers` returns the same json body as the one loaded from, `apiResponse1.json` (I checked that `apiResponse1.json` is properly loaded)

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ExtractorTest {
    Extractor extractor = new Extractor();

    @Mock
    HttpClient client;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpRequest httpRequest;

    @Test
    public void testGetManagers() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        HashMap<String, String> parametters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        parametters.put("SrcGender", "F");
        // Here        
        Mockito.when(response.body()).thenReturn(Resources.toString(Resources.getResource("apiResponse1.json"), Charsets.UTF_8));

        String response = extractor.getManagers(parametters);
        .....
```

### Issue

It looks like I failed to properly mock `response.body()`, for I end up with

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.comecompany.cockpit.ExtractorTest.testGetManagers(ExtractorTest.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
....
```

I think that the problem comes from what I include in `@Mock` (tried several combinaisons). I probably mis-transposed the logic of how I handle these cases in `pytest` to `org.mockito.Mockito`. When I only include `HttpResponse response;` in `@Mock`, I get a `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException` I do not entirely understand.

What should I include in @Mock to inject this Json file when `response.body()` is called? Should I mock '*one degree before*' (`response` or `HttpResponse<String> response`)?

### Environnement

- openjdk11
- mockito-junit-jupiter 2.23.0
- junit-jupiter-api 5.7.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `@Mock` annotation before each field

```
@Mock
HttpClient client;
@Mock
HttpResponse response;
@Mock
HttpRequest httpRequest;
```

Comment: It solves the exception issue but `response.body()` does not seem mocked -- i.e. it seems that I get responses from the actual API rather than `apiResponse1.json`

Comment: if you are calling the actual API you will get response from it. You need to do something like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564533/how-to-mock-remote-rest-api-in-unit-test-with-spring

Comment: I though that `org.mockito.Mockito` works like patches (like python's `MagikMock`). I was probably wrong

Comment: I'm attempting something similar but I'm mocking `client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());` so I can return the actual result with all my desired response info; 201 status, body, headers etc. BUT, I can't mock the result because it requires a CompletableFuture and I haven't managed to create an object properly for it.